# Bug when adding a 6th comment?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have the same odd behaviour, when adding a 6th comment to a question as in
[this example](http://answers.ros.org/question/1376/no-such-file-or-directory-when-using-rosrun)?

Usually after 5 comments, you see a "see more"-like link.

- When I post the 6th comment, it does not appear.
- Once I post another 7th comment, the 6th and 7th comment appear.
- If I delete the 7th comment again, the 6th comment also disappears.
- I can readd and delete the 6th comment be readding and deleting a 7th comment multiple times.

I obviously tried reloading the page after posting the comments. It doesn't change anything.

Is it just me or a bug for anyone else, maybe upstream?

Edit: I can see exactly 6 comments by Erik Perko. This question is a bit problematic as commenting properly doesn't allow testing ;)

Edit: Sorry for abusing the other question, but it seems solved.
Can anyone see a 6th comment to the original question by me as:

"Can you put a minimal python script in the same location as the script in question. Just the #! and a printout. If that rosruns (what I'd expect) its some problem in your code. - dornhege (9 hours ago)"

I deleted the 7th comment again and it does not appear for me. Can others see it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10453/bug-when-adding-a-6th-comment?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to be working for me... I just added those 6 test comments to this question. After adding the 6th one, I saw it show up (but no show more link). I then refreshed and I saw the first 5 comments and a show more link. Seems to be working for me. Maybe there's something to reproduce it that I missed?

Also, anyone, feel free to delete all of my test comments in order to test for yourselves.

UPDATE: I cannot see the specific comment on the other question. I suppose this is a bug then...

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-26**:
The askbot guys are requesting to retry this bug with 0.7.7.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-22**:
I'm planning to upgrade soon.  Hopefully this will be fixed.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-02**:
Now I only see 5 on the page.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-01**:
Same here. Only 5 comments. Still on the linked example question.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-01**:
OK, that's weird. Is it account specific? For me the linked question still has 5 comments.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-30**:
I can see your 6th comment and I could add a 7th too.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-30**:
Deleted. Maybe only the poster or people with ROS Answers super-powers can delete them ;)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-30**:
I think others can't delete them. Maybe they need to be mixed? I can still reproduce it on the other question...